# How to set default date using angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker module for user to select date and time , How can i add defualt dateandtime when view renders ? do we have any attribute that we can set booleab value or any other better appraoch ?

main.html

```
<div class="dropdown form-group">
    <!-- <label>Start Date</label> -->
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownStart" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateRangeStart" placeholder=" Search Start Date">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed' }" data-on-set-time="startDateOnSetTime()" data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($dates)"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ctrl.js

```
    $scope.endDateBeforeRender = endDateBeforeRender
        $scope.endDateOnSetTime = endDateOnSetTime
        $scope.startDateBeforeRender = startDateBeforeRender
        $scope.startDateOnSetTime = startDateOnSetTime

        function startDateOnSetTime () {
          $scope.$broadcast('start-date-changed');
        }

        function endDateOnSetTime () {
          $scope.$broadcast('end-date-changed');
        }

        function startDateBeforeRender ($dates) {
          if ($scope.dateRangeEnd) {
            var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeEnd);

            $dates.filter(function (date) {
                $scope.searchObj.endDate = activeDate._i;
                // console.log(activeDate);
              return date.localDateValue() >= activeDate.valueOf()
            }).forEach(function (date) {
              date.selectable = false;
              // console.log(date);
            })
          }
        }

function endDateBeforeRender ($view, $dates) {
      if ($scope.dateRangeStart) {
        var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeStart).subtract(1, $view).add(1, 'minute');

        $dates.filter(function (date) {
            $scope.searchObj.startDate = activeDate._i;
            // console.log(activeDate._i);
          return date.localDateValue() <= activeDate.valueOf()
        }).forEach(function (date) {
          date.selectable = false;
          // console.log(date);
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `data-ng-model` attribute to a default value:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart"></datetimepicker>
```

In your controller give `dateRangeStart` a default value:

```
$scope.dateRangeStart = new Date();
```

Comment: How can i specify if i want start date with time lets say 1:00AM to 11:55PM ? is it possible ?

Comment: You could specify the time you want in the JavaScript `Date` object. I don't think it'd be possible to specify multiple times.

Comment: what you mean by multiple times ?

Comment: I'm not sure that the attribute can accept a time range. You would have to read up on the documentation to determine if this is possible.